# Adding '|' to FASTA file headers in bash

Tags: bash, fasta

I have 48411 K FASTA sequences, each 1555 characters in length (in a single file, 78.3 Mb total) with headers as follows:

```
CYTC2889-12 HM036578 Homo sapiens
```

but unfortunately, spaces have been used to delimit text instead of the usual '|' (I think).

I'd like to add '|' to headers so that they become

```
CYTC2889-12|HM036578|Homo sapiens
```

I just need to replace the first two spaces. There should not be a pipe in the species name. Thus, the end result should be "Homo sapiens" not "Homo | sapiens".

I'm unsure how to proceed since all spaces would be replaced by a pipe instead of just within the first two identifiers (CYTC2889-12 and HM036578 in the above example) as pointed out by @CharlesDuffy.

It seems like a simple task (?), but I'm getting thrown off by the use of spaces as delimiters (or so I assume this is how spaces are being used).

Any thoughts?

Comment: BTW, how large are these files? If they're huge enough to make the performance needed to rewrite the whole thing in-place prohibitive, this is the kind of change where that can actually be avoided (because the number of output bytes is exactly identical to the number of input bytes). Normal `sed -i` processes do the create-and-rename dance, so they need to write the entire file content out to disk; not so great if it's measured in gigabytes.

Comment: Getting back to the problem, though... do you know that there are exactly three columns, and that the first two can't contain spaces, so you just need to replace the first two spaces with `|`s? Otherwise, how is your code supposed to know that the space between `Homo` and `sapiens` doesn't need to become a pipe as well?

Comment: (btw, `head -n 1 | hexdump -C` or similar might be worth doing ahead-of-time just to be sure that the assumption that these really are regular spaces can be validated; it'd be a shame to do the work and then discover that the characters are actually tabs, or Unicode non-breaking spaces, or so forth).

Comment: is that 50K sequences in a single file? or 50K files each with a sequence? can you provide a sample input file showing header and non-header data?  at this point I'm a bit confused as to how to determine which row is a header vs non-header ... some additional context would help

Comment: @markp-fuso It's 50000 sequences in a single file

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There should not be a pipe in the species name. It should be "Homo sapiens" not "Homo | sapiens". That's where I'm a a bit lost on how to best tackle.

Comment: Here's the thing: We can help you figure out how to turn your desired business logic into code, but it's your job to decide on the logic you want, and be specific about the technical problem that prevents you from implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP hasn't provided a sample set of data showing header and non-header files so based on other fasta-related questions I'm going to *guess* the only lines with spaces are header lines.

Setup:

```
$ cat bogus.fasta
>CYTC2889-12 HM036578 Homo sapiens
CCATCATTGGCGTCTACA
>CYTC2889-12 HM036578 Homo sapiens
CCATCATTGGCGTCTACA
>CYTC2889-12 HM036578 Homo sapiens
CCATCATTGGCGTCTACA
>CYTC2889-12 HM036578 Homo sapiens
CCATCATTGGCGTCTACA
```

One `sed` idea to replace the 1st two spaces with a pipe (`|`):

```
$ sed 's/ /|/1;s/ /|/1' bogus.fasta
>CYTC2889-12|HM036578|Homo sapiens
CCATCATTGGCGTCTACA
>CYTC2889-12|HM036578|Homo sapiens
CCATCATTGGCGTCTACA
>CYTC2889-12|HM036578|Homo sapiens
CCATCATTGGCGTCTACA
>CYTC2889-12|HM036578|Homo sapiens
CCATCATTGGCGTCTACA
```

Where:

- the 1st `s/ /|/1` says to replace the 1st space we find with a pipe; this modified line now becomes the input for the 2nd half of the script where ...
- the 2nd `s/ /|/1` also says to replace the 1st space we find with a pipe (which in this case is actually the 2nd space from the original file)

If the results look correct and OP wants to actually modify the original file then ... and assuming  using `GNU sed` ... the `-i` flag can be added to force the input file to be updated with the changes, eg:

```
sed -i 's/ /|/1;s/ /|/1' bogus.fasta
```

Comment: This works. However, as I am a Mac user, I had to specify a backup extension as `sed -i '.bak' 's/ /|/1;s/ /|/1' bogus.fasta`